# Unable to load NSMutableArray from CoreData store

Tags: core-data, ios6, nsmutablearray, xcode4.6

I have a NSMUtableArray that I am trying to load from a Core Data store (there is valid data in the store); this is the code:

```
    [unsortedArray addObject:storedServices.aCustomServices1];
    [unsortedArray addObject:storedServices.aCustomServices2];
```

The array is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *unsortedArray;
```

I can load the array using static data which works:

```
        unsortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                     NSLocalizedString(@"Property1",nil),
                     NSLocalizedString(@"Property2",nil),nil];
```

The problem is although there is valid data in the CD store, the array remains empty.  I have searched Google and SO but found nothing related.  Why can I not load from the Core Data store?

Comment: You don't mention what the exact issue is.  Exception?  Empty array?

Comment: Oops... sorry... I just updated the question...

Comment: What are you trying to do that gives you unwanted results? Your code snippet tells us what you are **not** doing. What code are you using that isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a punt that you haven't allocated `unsortedArray`.  Try:

```
self.unsortedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[self.unsortedArray addObject:storedServices.aCustomServices1];
[self.unsortedArray addObject:storedServices.aCustomServices2];
```

This assumes you have `unsortedArray` getter/setter methods that conform to normal MRR memory management practices.  This is as simple as using `@synthesize unsortedArray` (although newer versions of clang do this for you, I'd still explicitly add it).

Note that:

```
self.unsortedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Should be in your `init` method.

Comment: Unbelievable!  I can't believe I forgot something like that!  Thank you so much... I've spent 4 hours on this;  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @spokane-dude The old ones are always the best :D (I mean the old problems, not the old coders)...

Comment: Applies to me - I'm going to be 71 years old this year... have been coding since 1966 (worked on first IBM 360 delivered in Los Angeles)... how's that for being old?  :D

Comment: @spokane-dude Blimey; you're the oldest coder I've heard of!  I bet you miss punch cards and teletypes, don't you :D

Comment: Punch cards were a real pain when you dropped them... been there, done that!